# Websphere JMS queue size

Tags: memory, jms, message-queue, websphere-7

I am using WebSphere Application Server  7.0.0.29.

Have setup a JMS implementation with. Bus + Connection Factory + Queues + Activation Specs + Destinations.

Wanted to know, how can i see the Destination Size, Number of messages it holds?
If this is dependent on memory, how much memory is allocated to a Destination?

Note this is not WebSphere MQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of researching on the web, found the solution on one of IBM's pages:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6rxmx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.btools.help.monitor.doc/Doc/tasks/administration/ad_settingthequeuedestinationsize.html

Copying it here in case the link becomes inactive in the future...

1.From the WebSphere Application Server administrative console, go to Service integration > Buses.
 2.In the Name column, click *busName*, where the busName is the name of the bus where your queue is defined.
3.Click the Destinations.
4.Click *destinationName*.
5.Click Queue points.
6.Click *queuePointName* (for example Monitor_Bus_Queue_Destination@node_name.server_name- MONITOR.cell_name.Bus).
7.In the `High message threshold` field, type the value of the maximum queue size you want to use. The default value is 50000 messages.
8.Click OK.
9.In the Message information box, click Save to apply your changes. The Save page is displayed.
10.Click Save.

Note this is for WebSphere 6 but it will work the same in later versions as well.